# InDesign export particularly low quality image in an AI file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, shapes, image-quality, pixelation

I am creating a daily journal. I encountered problem when exporting interative pdf.
The blue and orange dots are pngs. When I place the ai files into indesign and export as interactive PDF, the dots turn out to be in low quality, while the dots are displayed in good quality in InDesign.

How can I solve this problem? :'(
[image]<InDesign Display
[image]<Exported PDF

Comment: Why are the "dots" PNGS if you are using Illustrator? They are merely circles, why not draw them with *vector* tools in *either* AI or INDD?

Comment: Random side note.. having the 09 be the place where numbers "flip" is poor.. it can be 06 upside down (like the numbers above it) or 09 right side up (like the numbers below it)... I'd suggest you remain consistent with the numbers, don't "flip" them for half the circle.

Comment: The dots are in png so I can set it as a variable in illustrator, the position of dots change in 365 days . I am wondering is there a way to set vector as a variable?

Comment: Agreed with @Scott – you almost unavoidably read it as “01 – 03 – 05 – 07 – 60… wait, what?”. We’re used to (Roman) numerals following the circle on a clock face; I don’t think it would be much of a strain on the reader/user to apply the same logic here.

Comment: What are the export settings for the interactive PDF? Perhaps you choose low resolution (72 ppi). Or perhaps the physical dimensions of your document are low? A tiny circle will look pixelated even at 300 ppi. (I still don't understand why the circles have to be PNGs. Not knowing how you are doing this, I'm thinking if you can link to a PNG, can't you link to an AI instead?)

Comment: Thank you for all of the suggestions (I flipped the numbers at the lower half) and I solved the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: I want to have individual ai files with dots at different position to represent each day in the year. It is a waste of time if I reposition the dot one by one as I have to save 365 ai files by hand. Therefore, I first save 12 pngs with a dot at 12 different positions in a  transparent background, then set the png as a variable in illustrator, and use batch action to save the ai files automatically. This is the reason of using png instead of a shape. I am wondering, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think your question has bas been answered by @Lucian. What you ask now should be another question really. I guess you could do exactly like you do, but with AI files instead of PNG files. Isn't that possible? Personally I would do this in a more graphical  way. Setup 31x12 artboards with the background and rotate the circles using transform. Only have to make one row and duplicate 12 times vertically and one column and duplicate it 31 times horizontally. Remove the artboards with non-existing dates afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

- First, if you need to rule out pixelation, circles linked as PNG in AI is the incorrect approach. You should use proper vector shapes, you have a few circles, it takes a couple of clicks to put some circles on the page. Everything in that calendar should be vector shapes, not PNGs. That's the proper way to do it, which will result in *zero pixelation*.
- Second, if you must keep the PNG circles for some reason, check your image compression settings in the INDD Export panel. InDesign can *"pixelate"* the PNGs on export, depending on settings. Try using the "High Quality" preset when exporting.

Comment: Another thing could be if the document physically small. Then even 300 PPI will look pixelated when the PDF is blown up to fill the screen.

Comment: I think wolff is right: the OP doesn't tell us what size the page is and what size the image placed on that page is. I suspect these circles are sub 10px diameter, and when exported via PDF, they are downsampled by default PDF presets (aka "downsample to 150ppi when above Xppi" The indesign can zoom because the data is there (the effective ppi is very high).